# multi_query() has an error

Tags: php, mysql, multi-query

I need some help finding my error on the enclosed code.  When I run either of the two queries using the `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {` method each works correctly.  But when I try to combine them with the `if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {` method.  No records are uploaded.  What am I doing wrong here.

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "practice";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connection made...";

$payload_dump = $_POST['payload'];
echo $payload_dump;

$payload_array = json_decode($payload_dump,true);

if(is_array($payload_array)){
foreach($payload_array as $row){

//get the data_payload details

$device = $row['device'];
$type = $row['data_type'];
$zone = $row['zone'];
$sample = $row['sample'];
$count = $row['count'];
$time = $row['date_time'];
$epoch = $row['epoch_stamp'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO data(device, type, zone, sample, count, date_time, epoch_stamp) VALUES('$device', '$type', '$zone', '$sample', '$count', '$time', '$epoch');";
$sql . = "UPDATE data SET date_time = FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch_stamp);";
if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
//if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

... and yes I realize this code is not secure but it's ok for my testing purposes.

Comment: what did `$conn->error;` have to say?

Comment: plus, your update will try and update your entire table. Use a `where` clause.

Comment: Its being called from an Arduino and I don't know how to have display the error message back to shell.  My coding skills are pretty basic.

Comment: `echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;` that should be echoing something.

Comment: ok I think I know what the problem is `$sql . = "UPDATE` there's a space between the dot and the equal sign. Change that to `$sql .= "UPDATE`

Comment: taking out the space as suggested I get one record to import and update.

Comment: is that not how it should be? 1 record to insert and 1 to update per iteration through $payload?

Comment: ok so it's a partial fix. Now you need to figure out why the rest of it isn't being updated. As I said in an earlier comment, if your table has more than one row, it will attempt to update your entire table. Not sure if that's what you want here, but you'll need to add a `WHERE` clause in order to update a specific record.

Comment: plus, remove the semi-colon in `FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch_stamp);";` so that it reads as `FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch_stamp)";` the example in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php states `$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";`

Comment: If I run the first sql (insert into) by itself I get all the rows imported.  If I then run the (update) sql by itself.  All of the rows that were just imported are updated.  But if I run the two together only one row is inserted and updated.  I would think that combining the two statements sql would run the first query in its entirety and then run the next query, not iterate through the queries row by row.  Am I wrong on this?

Comment: As mentioned - you NEED a where clause to the update statement

Comment: Incidentally, I think you are missing the benefit of the multi query as you could, in theory, build up an array of queries to run in your loop, concatenate with a semi-colon once outside the loop and then execute the sql once

Comment: RamRaider- my intent at the moment is to update all records of the table.  Can you please explain how adding a WHERE clause will help?  I have never used a WHERE clause in an sql statement where all records are called.

Comment: Fred -ii-  Removing the semi-colon as suggested had not affect.  Still only one record imported.

Comment: Is it your intention to update all records on every iteration through the $payload array or can it be done once at the end?

Comment: it can be done at the end.  can you provide sample syntax of how to call second query in php?

Comment: if you have an `id` (int) column for example as a AI/PK, then use `UPDATE... WHERE id=1` for example. See if that makes it kick in. You may also want to take out your query outside the `foreach($payload_array as $row){...}` loop.

Comment: @RamRaider be my guest if you want to submit an answer. My only suggestion to the OP would be like you suggested. Perform the UPDATE inside a successful conditional INSERT statement.

Comment: Fred 'UPDATE... WHERE id=1' no go.

Comment: Last ditch effort: Try `$sql1 = "INSERT INTO...` - `$sql2 = "UPDATE data...` - 
`if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE) { $sql2 = $conn->query("UPDATE data... ");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrinsically the code below is the same until we get to the loop where we build up an array of queries to be executed and execute the multi_query() once at the end once we leave the loop. I have removed some of the comments and statements that echo out info at the start for brevity. I *hope* this looks ok and works....

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "practice";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if( $conn->connect_error ) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    $payload_dump = $_POST['payload'];

    $payload_array = json_decode($payload_dump,true);

    if( is_array( $payload_array ) ){

        $queries=array();

        foreach( $payload_array as $row ){
            //get the data_payload details
            $device = $row['device'];
            $type = $row['data_type'];
            $zone = $row['zone'];
            $sample = $row['sample'];
            $count = $row['count'];
            $time = $row['date_time'];
            $epoch = $row['epoch_stamp'];

            /*note: we do not need to add the semi-colon here as it gets added later when we implode the array */
            $queries[]="INSERT INTO `data` ( `device`, `type`, `zone`, `sample`, `count`, `date_time`, `epoch_stamp` ) VALUES ('$device', '$type', '$zone', '$sample', '$count', '$time', '$epoch')";
        }
        /*
            Previously the below query was being execute on every iteration
            ~ because $epoch is now the last one encountered in the array, 
            the value that is updated in ALL records is as it would have been
            previously.
        */
        $queries[]="UPDATE `data` SET `date_time` = from_unixtime( $epoch );";

        $sql=implode( ';', $queries );
        if ( $conn->multi_query( $sql ) === TRUE ) {
            echo "New records created and updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Gave the OP a *last ditch effort* comment about 10 mins. ago... no word from that yet.

Comment: Must be. It just ended here now lol and I still haven't had a bite to eat yet. No wonder my stomach was growling at me.

Comment: WHOOO HOOO!  works like a charm... sorry guys.  Day job called.  Thanks for your help... greatly appreciated.

Comment: aaahhh yes, another happy ending. Good job @RamRaider ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear it @ghowe So, I take it that [my comment here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254235/multi-query-has-an-error#comment52390333_32254235) didn't work then(?)